# How to get data in JSON format from a web server with authentication?

Tags: python, json, authentication, post

I am running a photovoltaic system with an inverter from Solax. This inverter is connected to the Solaxcloud. Solax offers an [API](https://www.eu.solaxcloud.com/phoebus/resource/files/userGuide/Solax_API.pdf?token=6667d350-78cd-42f7-aba0-cc5059a0b466&lang=de_DE) to get access to the live data.

I am used to offline embedded C programming but like to try something new. So I would like to use Python to handle the data from the inverter.

This is my script:

```
import os
import requests

os.system('cls')

url = ('https://www.eu.solaxcloud.com:9443/proxy/api/getRealtimeInfo.do?tokenId={myTokenId}&sn={mySn}')

user = 'abc'
password = 'test'

response = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user, password))
data     = response.json()

print('Status Code:', response.status_code)
print()
print('Header:', response.headers)
print()
print('Options:', requests.options(url))
print()
print('JSON content:\n',
      'Exception:', data['exception'], '\n'
      ' Result:   ', data['result'], '\n'
      ' Success:  ', data['success'])
input()
```

And this is my prompt:

```
Status Code: 200

Header: {'Server': 'nginx/1.14.2', 'Date': 'Thu, 15 Jul 2021 11:46:57 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authentication', 'vary': 'accept-encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}

Options: <Response [200]>

JSON content:
 Exception: Query success!
 Result:    no auth!
 Success:   False
```

On the one hand side I received JSON formatted data and got the status code 200, on the other side the result field in the JSON data is 'no auth!'.

Does anyone have an idea, what I am doing wrong or what is missing? If you guys need more information, just let me know.

Best regards

Comment: `status code 200` is not to inform if you send good or wrong JSON data but inform that server recognized URL and it could send response (good or wrong).

Comment: Okay, so at least the connection to the server is fine.

Comment: yes, connection is OK, `url` is correct, data is send in correct way, but it doesn't iform if you send correct values.

Comment: how do you create URL? I see url with `{myTokenId}&sn={mySn}` but I don't see variables `myTokenId = ...` and `mySn = ...` and it has to be `f-string` to replace values `{myTokenId}&sn={mySn}` in string. Maybe first display `URL` to see if you have correct values in URL.

Comment: documentation doesn't mention `auth=`. it needs only correct `TokenId` which gives acccess to values.

Comment: Oh, actually this is only anonymization. In my real script both numbers are written directly in the url string, so the url is correct.

Comment: maybe numbers are correct but maybe your `TokenId` doesn't give privileges to access device with this `Serial Number`. Maybe you have to create different token for this serial number.

Comment: One thing that tricked me is that the `sn` is not the inverter serial number, but rather the registration number that is visible in the Solax web UI in your device list. I noticed this because their docs ( https://www.eu.solaxcloud.com/phoebus/resource/files/userGuide/Solax_API_for_End-user_V1.0.pdf ) state that `sn` is a `STRING` of length `10`, while the module SN is longer.

Comment: oh yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of weird: I double checked everything and suddenly it was working!

```
JSON content:
 Exception: Query success!
 Result:    {'inverterSN': 'XMUxxx', 'sn': 'SWxxx', 'acpower': 8248.0, 'yieldtoday': 40.7, 'yieldtotal': 10159.2, 'feedinpower': 0.0, 'feedinenergy': 0.0, 'consumeenergy': 0.0, 'feedinpowerM2': None, 'soc': None, 'peps1': None, 'peps2': None, 'peps3': None, 'inverterType': 'x', 'inverterStatus': '102', 'uploadTime': '2021-07-15 15:14:55', 'batPower': None, 'powerdc1': xxx, 'powerdc2': xxx, 'powerdc3': xxx, 'powerdc4': xxx}
 Success:   True
```

And it seems that the problem is on the server site or the following behaviour is intended:
If I repeat my request 90%
of the time there is an error as result and 10% it works...

Comment: in documentation you see that it has restriction `"The obtain frequency need to be lower than 10 times/min and 10,000 times/day."` and it may also block responses.